# App Engine MapReduce mapper wrong model kind passed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

Hey I was following the documentation here: [Google MapReduce](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview.html)

```
class StationsBlobstoreHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
''''''
def get(self):
    mr_job = mapreduce_pipeline.MapPipeline(
        'calculate_sha1_stations_logos',
        'radioflag.admin.mapreduce.blobfixstations.station_avatar_mapper',
        'mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreEntityInputReader',
        {'entity_kind': 'myproj.engine.db.model.StationAvatar'})
    mr_job.start()

def station_avatar_mapper(station_avatar):
    logging.info(type(station_avatar))
```

But my mapper is called with  instead of myproj.engine.db.model.StationAvatar.

How can i get the right models in my mapper.

PS: Passing just StationAvatar to entity_kind did not work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I have found that i should use DatastoreInputReader instead of DatastoreEntityInputReader.

Sorry :)